# How do I make a Popup included in it's parent Control for the sake of mouse events?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Control that contains a Popup. I am trying to close the Popup whenever someone clicks outside of the Control. This is the part of my code that sets up the problem:

```
AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent, new MouseuttonEventHandler(HandleOutsideClick), true);
```

Now whenever I click in the Popup it causes PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent to be raised. Am  I misunderstanding this event? Is there something that I can do to have the Popup be considered a part of the Control so that it doesn't raise this event?

Comment: Try using the LostFocus method, and close it programmatically in the method called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<Popup Name="Pop" LostFocus="ClosePop"/>


private void ClosePop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Pop.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Put the XAML code in your .xaml page and the C# code in the related .xaml.cs file.

Note: You may need to put the focus on the popup before this works, it may be done automatically; I haven't done this on popups, but I have done it on other objects.

**Update:** This works for me, clicking in the TextBox that says Test1 opens the Popup, and clicking in the TextBox labeled Test2 closes it:

```
<Grid Background="White">

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Foreground="Black" LostFocus="ClosePop" GotFocus="OpenPop" Height="50">Test1</TextBox>
    <TextBox Foreground="Black" Height="50">Test2</TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
  <Popup Name="Pop" Height="50" Width="50">
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Pop!</TextBlock>
  </Popup>
</Grid>

private void ClosePop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Pop.IsOpen = false;
}

private void OpenPop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Pop.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: I have a TextBox attached to the Popup, the TextBox input filters the Popup items. I'm trying to close the Popup when I click outside of the whole control. I'm not sure how I would give the Popup focus appropriately in that situation.

Comment: Hmm, are you in the desktop-WPF?  I can try to build something and figure it out, but the desktop-WPF is different than the Windows Store-WPF, so I need to know which you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm in desktop-WPF.

Comment: This does work in the context I described. I realized that I have been going about my particular solution in the wrong way and have reworked it.